# IBM Blockchain Platform vscode extension error: Illegal group end indicator

Tags: visual-studio-code

The following message appears in vscode when the IBP extension becomes active or when I try to install smart contract to local fabric:

> Illegal group end indicator for Message .protos.ChaincodeDeploymentSpec: 2 (not a group).

End result is that I am unable to install a freshly packaged smart contract.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this was a bug that has now been fixed in the latest version of the IBM Blockchain Platform extension for Visual Studio Code. The bug was that if the packages folder contained anything other than smart contract packages (e.g. a .DS_Store file on a Mac), the extension failed with an exception. The fix resolves this problem and ignores anything other than smart contract packages.